# .Net BindingDictionary

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, collections

I have started using BindingList(Of T) for my generic collections whenever I need the objects to interface with the GUI instead of List(Of T). This has worked well for me so far but a few of my collections are stored in Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue) and there doesn't appear to be a corresponding BindingDictionary(Of T).

Has anyone else come across the necessity to use this, and how did they achieve it? Should I implement this myself? (How?) or is there a better solution already available?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to unroll your dictionary into a BindingList(Of [KeyValuePair(Of TKey, TValue)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)) but I'm not sure if it will provide all of the behavior you are trying to achieve.